# query executing too much time

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, query-performance

1. my query is taking around 2800 secs to get output.
2. we have indexes also but no luck.
3. my target is need to get the output with in 2 to 3 seconds.
4. if possible please re-write the query.

   ```
   query:
    select ttl.id, ttl.url, ttl.canonical_url_id  
    from t_target_url ttl  
    where ttl.own_domain_id=476 and ttl.type != 10  
    order by ttl.week_entrances desc  
    limit 550000;

   Explain Plan:
   +----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+-------+----------+-----------------------------+
   | id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                  | key                       | key_len | ref   | rows     | Extra                       |
   +----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+-------+----------+-----------------------------+
   |  1 | SIMPLE      | ttl   | ref  | own_domain_id_type_status,type | own_domain_id_type_status | 5       | const | 57871959 | Using where; Using filesort |
   +----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+-------+----------+-----------------------------+
   1 row in set (0.80 sec)


   mysql> show create table t_target_url\G
   *************************** 1. row ***************************
          Table: t_target_url
   Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t_target_url` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `own_domain_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `url` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
     `create_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
     `friendly_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
     `section_name_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `week_entrances` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'last 7 days entrances',
     `week_bounces` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'last 7 days bounce',
     `canonical_url_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'the primary URL ID, NOT allow canonical of canonical',
     KEY `id` (`id`),
     KEY `urlindex` (`url`(255)),
     KEY `own_domain_id_type_status` (`own_domain_id`,`type`,`status`),
     KEY `canonical_url_id` (`canonical_url_id`),
     KEY `type` (`type`,`status`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=227984392 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
   /*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (`type`)
   (PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (0) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION pEOW VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */
   1 row in set (0.00 sec)
   ```

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the distribution of the data, but I'd at least _try_ a composite index on `own_domain_id, type, week_entrances`.

Comment: I will almost guarantee you that MySQL will not send 550k records in 2 seconds, even with the most efficient query on earth.

Answer (score 4):

Your query itself looks fine, however, the order by clause, and possible half-million records is probably your killer.  I would add an index to help optimize that portion via

( own_domain_id, week_entrances, type )

So this way, you are first hitting your critical key "own_domain_id", and then getting everything already in order.  The type is for != 10, thus any other type and would appear to cause more problems if that was in the second index position.

Comment Feedback.

For simplistic purposes, your critical key per the where clause is "ttl.own_domain_id=476".  You only care about data for domain ID 476.  Now, lets assume you have 15 "types" that span all different week entrances, such as

```
own_domain_id   type   week_entrances
476             1      1000
476             1      1700
476             1      850
476             2      15000
476             2      4250
476             2      12000
476             7      2500
476             7      5300
476            10      1250
476            10      4100
476            12      8000
476            12      3150
476            15      5750
476            15      27000
```

This obviously is not to scale of your half-million capacity, but shows sample data.
By having the type != 10, it will STILL have to blow through all the records for id=476, yet exclude only those with the type = 10.  It then has to put all the data in order by the week entrances which would take more time.  By having the week entrances as part of the key in the second position, THEN the type, the data WILL BE able to be optimized in the returned result set already in proper order.  However, when it gets to the type of "!= 10", it will still skip over those quickly as they are encountered.  Here would be the revised index data per above sample.

```
own_domain_id   week_entrances  type   
476             850             1
476             1000            1
476             1250            10
476             1700            1
476             2500            7
476             3150            12
476             4100            10
476             4250            2
476             5300            7
476             5750            15
476             8000            12
476             12000           2
476             15000           2
476             27000           15
```

So, as you can see, the data is already pre-sorted per the index, and applying DESCENDING order is no problem for the engine, just pulls the records in reverse order and skips the 10's as they are found.

Does that help?

Additional comment feedback per Salman.

Think of this another way with a store with 10 different branch locations, each with their own sales.  The transactions receipts are stored in boxes (literally). Think of how you would want to go through the boxes if you were looking for all transactions on a given date.

```
Box 1 = Store #1 only, and transactions sorted by date
Box 2 = Store #2 only, and transactions sorted by date
Box ...
Box 10 = Store #10 only, sorted by date.
```

You have to go through 10 boxes, pulling out all for a given date...  Or in the original question, every transaction EXCEPT for one date, and you want them in order by dollar amount of transaction, regardless of date...  What a mess that could be.

If you had the boxes pregroup sorted, regardless of store

```
Box 1 = Sales from $1 - $1000 (all properly sorted by amount)
Box 2 = Sales from $1001 - $2000 (properly sorted)
Box ...
Box 10... same...
```

You STILL have to go through all the boxes and put them in order, but at least, as you are looking through the transactions, you could just throw out the one for the date exclusion to ignore.

Indexes help pre-organize how the engine can best go through them for your criteria.

Comment: can you please explain clearly about((The type is for != 10, thus any other type and would appear to cause more problems if that was in the second index position)).    i heard some where..query's which is using not equal will not follow the indexing techiiques..

Comment: @mithunakous, see revised answer for feedback to your comment

Comment: Does it make a difference if `type` is 3rd and `week_entrances` is 2nd column in the index?

Comment: you can as well as omit the `type` from index because `!=` is not distinct enough

Comment: @ImreL, I agree, type no longer applicable (in this case)

Comment: @mithunakous, glad it was helpful, but did it improve your querying performance needs?

Comment: I would also add id, url, canonical_url_id to the index to save disk seeks, especially since 550k records are required.